# How to return multiple values using index/match?

Tags: excel

I have the below simple table:

```
A   1
B   2
C   2
D   1
```

Using an index/match formula, I have set it up so that it only looks at one row at a time.

However, when I drag this formula down and ask it to return where the second column is a 2. I receive N/A at the top and bottom of my lookup.

Is there a way for me to ask it to skip when there is a NA or return multiple rows?

Here is my code:

```
=INDEX(B2,MATCH(1,C2))
```

Which returns:

```
A   1       A
B   2       #N/A
C   2       #N/A
D   1       D
```

I would like it to return:

```
A   1       A
B   2       D
C   2       
D   1
```

So skiiping rows where there is no match.

Comment: momments like this your code would be really nice

Comment: whoops - code added :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to have it skip what the value is NA is to either put an IF statement

```
=If(A1 = "NA","",INDEX(MATCH))
```

or
If it is NA because it is not finding a match

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(MATCH),"")
```

one of those 2 should do it. If not please post your code.

Comment: @Keva161 so with my formula you get blanks, but instead you want no blank just skipped lines? If that is the case you will have to write a macro which will be more complex

Comment: have to? the answer does it above? #confused